# I just started using android and am having trouble with a reverseWord method

Tags: java, android

I made a method `reverseWord` that is supposed to reverse an inputted word and display it.

```
public void reverseEncrypt(View v)
    {

    // Get the input
    EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    TextView output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);
    TextView output2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_test);
    output2.setText("Test is complete");

    // Reverse word
    String text = input.getText().toString();
    String word = " ";
    for (int i = text.length(); i > 0; i--)
    {
        word += text.substring(i,i-1);
    }
    output2.setText(text);

    // Output result
    output.setText("Result: " + word);

}
```

The method works fine until I output the string `word` or `text`. Other test outputs work, but when I try to output `word` or `text` it crashes. I think it isn't receiving the input correctly, but I am really not sure.

This is probably a relatively easy fix, so any help would be appreciated. If you need anymore information to help me, please do not hesitate.

Comment: Why don't you show us the crash?

Comment: Logs please....

Comment: My android phone just says "My Application has stopped working".

Comment: Android Studio should have the crash log in the console... assuming the app crashed while the phone is connected.

Comment: Post also the log in the question

Comment: The app crashes on a button click, so android studio just says application terminated

Comment: @JakeBarcelona - It doesn't matter , Android studio will record the crash log regardless...

Comment: Look into your **logcat**. Android logs everything to this. And Android Studio has support for displaying your logcat logs

Comment: 05/11 14:20:48: Launching app
$ adb install-multiple -r -p com.example.barcelja.myapplication /Users/barcelja/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_3.apk /Users/barcelja/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk 
Split APKs installed
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.barcelja.myapplication/com.example.barcelja.myapplication.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 10705 on device lge-vs990-VS9903b96629a
Application terminated.

Comment: this is all the console displays

Comment: Is it possible that your output textview is null? maybe because it's defined in another layout .xml file

Answer (score 0):

I did not test it all, but your way of reversing the String did not work for me.

For me this reversed the String and printed it.

```
String text = "hello";
String reverse = new StringBuffer(text).reverse().toString();
System.out.println(reverse);
```

if you put that in your code, it should work

Comment: Thank you, kind stranger. I was not aware there was a reverse method or a StringBuffer class.